# Is matrix with entries $a_{ij} = x_ix_j$ positive semidefinite?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

I wonder if I can proof that the square matrix with entries $a_{ij} = x_ix_j$ for a given vector $x$ is positive semidefinite.

I hope it is because this matrix is somehow related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956541/mean-square-error-using-linear-regression-gives-a-convex-function) question where I asked if mean square error is convex function in linear regression. I actually calculated the Hessian matrix and obtained the one I give you (multiplied by 2). The problem is that I don't know how to proof that it is positive semidefinite so that I can show that mean square error is convex. Please give a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: What do you think the sign of $\sum\limits_{i,j}a_{ij}u_iu_j$ could be, for every $(u_i)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily check that $A=xx^T$. Then, for any $y$,
$$
y^TAy=y^Txx^Ty=(x^Ty)^Tx^Ty\geq0. 
$$

Comment: Or prove that the eigenvalues are $\|x\|^2$ (Euclidean norm) and $0$. `;-)`

Comment: Yes, after first proving that $A$ is symmetric :)

Answer (score 2):

If $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is the row vector, then $A=x^Tx$. So give a column vector $y$, you have that $y^TAy=(y^Tx^T)(xy)=(xy)^T(xy)$. What is that never negative?