# Is $xy$ a concave or convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis

What we say about the convexity, quasiconvexity, concavity and quasiconcavity of this function?

The Hessian is $$\begin{bmatrix}
y &1 \\ 
 1& x
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can't say anything about the sign unless we know the values of x and y.

Comment: Updated. The hessian does not help

Comment: Related: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580034/is-xy-concave-or-convex-or-neither-in-strict-positive-orthant)

Comment: Your Hessian is not right, recheck the calculations.

Comment: What is the domain of the function?  How about checking on the line joining the two points $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$.