# Is the function $F(x, y) = \frac{1}{y\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i}$ convex (repost)?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Hi here is a repost of the original question, which had been closed due to "This question needs details or clarity" and then automatically deleted.

**Question:** Consider the function $F(x, y) = \frac{1}{y\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i}$ with variables $x_i >0 \ \forall i$ and $y >0$. Is it a convex function?
I know $\frac{1}{x_iy}$ and $\frac{1}{x_i+x_j}$ are convex functions for any $x_i, x_j >0$ and $y >0$, but how about the case where the denominator is the sum of product?

**Comments of the original post:**

Ted Shifrin: If $f>0$, is it true that $1/f$ is convex if and only if $f$ is concave?

@Ted Shifrin: Thanks for the comment. I think it should be "if $f>0$, $1/f$ is convex if $f$ is concave", instead of "if and only if". The function $f(x,y) = xy$ is neither convex or concave, hence the reciprocal rule does not work for this problem.

jDAQ: Did you check if $g(z,y)=\frac{1}{zy}$ is convex? Also, notice that composition with an affine mapping preserves convexity, that is, for $g$ convex you have that $f(z)=g(Az+b)$ is convex (if $Az+b$ in dom $f$ of course.)

@jDAQ: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I have checked that the hessian matrix of $g(z,y)=\frac{1}{zy}$ is positive semidefinite. But I do not understand the affine mapping here. What is $z$ and what is the specific function of $Az+b$? Could you please clarify more? Thanks.

Comment: Such posts are not "automatically" deleted, and no post is deleted "due to no answer".

Comment: I don't understand your reply to Ted Shifrin. You said $\frac1{xy}$ (for $x,y>0$) is convex and $xy$ is not concave.

Comment: @AnneBauval FYI, although you're technically correct that no post is deleted just "due to no answer", there are several conditions for which the automated cleanup script, called "Roomba", will delete an unanswered question. These conditions are listed in this network Meta FAQ [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222). Since the OP hasn't provided a link to the original question, I can't determine what the actual reason is. Nonetheless, assuming the question wasn't closed, then I suspect item #$10$ is the most likely cause, i.e., ...

Comment: @AnneBauval (cont.) "The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) unlocked, unanswered questions older than $365$ days on main (non-meta) sites, that have a score of zero (or have a score of $1$ and the owner's account is deleted), have fewer than $1.5$ views per day on average, and fewer than two comments. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedQuestions" in the question timeline)"

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you very much for these informations and links! (Though I suspect the original question was recent.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes the original one is a recent post. I re-check the reason for automatic delete, it should be the case "closed more than 9 days ago and no accepted answer".

Comment: @AnneBauval The system gives the reason of closing the original one that "This question needs details or clarity". However, I think I have clearly describe the question, just the same as I show in the new post.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks a lot for your link and inference! :) I re-checked and it should be "closed more than 9 days ago and no accepted answer". The original post is closed due to "This question needs details or clarity". However, I think I have clearly describe the question, just the same as I show in the new post.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, f(x,y)=xy is not concave. More information: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580034/is-xy-concave-or-convex-or-neither-in-strict-positive-orthant

Comment: Yes, I know, but then why did you answer "It is true" to Ted Shifrin? It is contradictory. + thanks for your explanation about the deletion, which was automatic but as a consequence of a closure by votes. I agree your question is very clear, but it might be better considered if you present some deeper attempts.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for reminding, it is not true. It should be "if" rather than "if and only if".